# APPDATA in .bat or .cmd does not print proper name with space

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have different users that have name with space and no space : John Doe, Jane Susy
I tried typing %APPDATA% in command prompt, and all i get is John / Jane.

How should i script my batch/cmd file, so it supports folder with spaces?

```
Copy /y %APPDATA%\Folder\Templates\abc.txt %APPDATA%\Folder\Templates\FoldABC >nul
```

when i use echo %AppData% i get the full name John Doe / Jane Susy.
When i just type %AppData% , i get John / Jane

I am trying to do the following:

```
if exist %APPDATA%\Folder\Templates\abc.txt (
   Copy /y %APPDATA%\Folder\Templates\abc.txt %APPDATA%\Folder\Templates\FoldABC >nul
)
```

Here is the error i get :

```
if exist C:\Users\John Doe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\abc.txt(
'Doe\AppData\Roaming\Folder\Templates\abc.txt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Appdata is underneath a User and every User has an Appdata. What (in words) are you trying to do?

Comment: You would normally encapsulate the path in double quotations, however that generally shouldn't be needed with default environment variables. What does `echo %AppData%` return? If double quotes doesn't work, try `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming`, otherwise you could echo the `%UserName%` within the path, but that shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 1):

Put every path with spaces between quotes:

```
Copy /y "%APPDATA%\Folder\Templates\abc.txt" "%APPDATA%\Folder\Templates\FoldABC" >nul
```

Comment: Great, it works on the if statements and also the command. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help